# Understanding Drupal core?

Tags: drupal

I know there is [Pro Drupal Dev](http://www.drupalbook.com/) for doing dev work on top of Drupal, but does anyone have suggestions for best places to look to understand the insides of Drupal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

... just wonder, would not stepping though some of the code with Xdebug be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Pro Drupal Dev is a great book to learn how to interface with Drupal, and by learning how Drupal works from that end will tell you a lot of how it works inside.

If you mean learning how to use Drupal's core effectively, there's a book titled 'Using Drupal' by a lot of the lullabots which will tell you how to set up a lot of items.

And then behind there, there's a lot of good stuff at api.drupal.org - dig in and look about and see how things are cross-referenced.

And finally, dig into the code and see what's going on yourself.

Comment: +1 PDD is simply the best and most comprehensive resource out there (excluding the drupal.org site, that however has an overwhelming low signal-to-noise ration). The suggestion of looking at the api subdomain is a good one. The only part that is weakly covered by PDD is js. For that one in particular I would suggest "Drupal 6 JavaScript and jQuery" b Matt Butcher - Packt Publishing.

Answer (score 2):

I found it most beneficial to create themes and develop my own modules to get a feel for the internal structure of Drupal.  Pro Drupal Development was very helpful, as was just reading through some of the code itself (starting at the hook level and working downward).

Comment: Reading through the API documentation and understanding things like how hooks are called (module_invoke_all) helped me more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

[This post by eaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068556/how-drupal-works/1069613#1069613) does a pretty good job of explaining how Drupal works, if that's what you mean.