# I want learn about the structure of Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

now I want learn about the structure of Drupal platform.Can you tell me the book for beginning ? I don't know what to begin, thanks.

Comment: A quick google search should get you started.

Comment: The first result for "drupal structure" on google yields this very helpful guide: http://drupal.org/documentation/structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068556/863380). Also as @CIGuy suggested, take a look at [Drupal structure](http://drupal.org/documentation/structure).